# Does the implementation of hadoop reducer relies on a big hash map to dedup all same keys?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How does the implementation of hadoop map reduce reducer looks like?

For example give the following file

```
k1 -> v1
k1 -> v2
k1 -> v3
```

A naive way of implementing reducer is the following

```
0. init an empty map
1. receive k1 -> v1
2. since k1 does not exist in map put k1->v1 into map with key k1
3. receive k1 -> v2
4. k1 is already in map, fetch k1 -> v1 in map and dedup it with k1 -> v2 and store it
4. k1 is already in map, fetch k1 -> v3 in map and dedup it with k1 in the amp and store the result
```

back into map

This requires `O(cardinality(k))` memory for map.

This seems super inefficient.

Is this how reducer is implemented?

Comment: it is not one single map for all the keys. The hash of the key is computed, then shuffle-sorted into a single reducer for all that key. Thereby, partitioning and bucketing, causing a de-duplication. As far as "what it looks like" or "how it is implemented", Hadoop is open-source...